# Why does logging this objects properties give a different result then logging the object itself and looking at the properties?

Tags: javascript

I currently am trying to set up socket-io with react redux right now, and I appear to be running into a weird namespace issue

```
console.log(socket);
console.log(socket.disconnected);
console.log(socket.id);
console.log(socket);
```

The first log returns a large object, and here are two of the properties.

```
disconnected: false;
id: PuAi01tcCcZgmJaAACM
```

the second and third logs, however, return completely different things than the object originally said. Logging socket.disconnected returns true, and logging socket.id returns undefined.

In case the socket was somehow mutating in between logs, I put the last log down. It returns the original log, where disconnected is false and id exists.

This seems to be some weird namespace issue? I don't see how it could've happened, but there appears to be two different socket names, and accessing a property of the name socket seems to target one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

If you don't want the log of your object to update live in modern browsers, parse your object to a string before you log it:

```
const example = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(JSON.stringify(example));
// or with pretty printing: 
console.log(JSON.stringify(example, null, 2));
```

**Explanation**

In modern browsers, `console.log` does not log a string, it logs a reference to the actual javascript object in memory. So by the time you're looking at the logged object, all your javascript has run and the object has been mutated.

```
const example = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(example);
example.foo = 'baz';
// log will say { foo: 'baz' } (usually with a note that the value is live)
```

When you log an object's property, if that property is immutable (like a string, boolean or number) it will log the value of the object rather than a reference. So if you change a string after you've logged it, the original won't change in the console.

```
let example = 'foo';
console.log(example);
example = 'bar';
// log will say 'foo'
```